# JSON string, starts with array

Tags: json

I have the following strings:

```
[{"result": True}]
[{"result": False}, {"info": "Describing error}]
```

Does this strings are correct JSON strings? Or I should use smth. like this:

```
{"result": False, "info": "error"}
```

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one is a valid JSON string (an array with one element). The second is missing a quote, but after fixing that it is valid.

Comment: It is running inside of my head. jsonlint.com resolves to the IP of my brain.

Comment: geek .. I'm not working with JSON on an every month basis. Not even on an every year basis ..

Answer (score 0):

First one would resolve to an Array with one Dictionary

Second one would resolve to an Array with two Dictionaries (BTW you are missing the end quote on your string)

Third one would resolve to a Dictionary.

It will all depend on how you will want/need to consume the JSON response.  All three of these can be consumed, just depends on your situation.